# The target entry-point "ng2-redux" has missing dependencies got error in angular

Tags: angular, ng2-redux

When [ng2-redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-redux/v/5.1.2) successfully installed and want to run ng serve I got this error.
[image: angular cli]

Entry point implementation in main.ts

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Rootreducer in app.module.ts.

```
export class AppModule {constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>) {this.ngRedux.configureStore(rootReducer, { counter: 0 });}}
```

Error listed missing dependencies even I have installed latest [rxjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs).Here package.json
[image: in package.json]

let me know. What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you reviece this error due to deprecation of the library, first thing you see when visiting their page on npm is

> This package has been deprecated Author message:
>
> This package has moved. Please 'npm install @angular-redux/store'
> instead.

Have you tried installing npm install @angular-redux/store instead? If not, can you try installing it?